# Google analytics event goal not creating conversion

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am using GA to analyze button click but it doesnt show them in the goal section. It just get displayed in the real time section.
My configuration:

[Google Analytics configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efblB.png)

Event sent via my onclick

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Buttonclick', 'Moveto', 'Register')
```

Comment: The code looks fine and so does the goal config. You won't be able to see the goals in the standard reports as it takes up to 24 hours for the data to be processed. You should be able to see it convert in real-time though under the "Conversions" section. Note that goals only convert once per session, so you may need to clear your cookies each time you test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks good to me, too. You can confirm the event is actually firing with the "Google Analytics Debugger" Chrome extension. As long as that works properly, then you're golden.